# jQuery slideDown() animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidedown

I'm trying to get jQuery's `slideDown()` animation to work, but in my case the text that should *slide down*, just *appears* .. How do I make it appear with the animation in place too ?

I tried manually specifying the speed too, but end result was the same.

**HTML:**

```
<section class="subscribe">
    <button id="submitBtn" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
    <p></p>
</section>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#submitBtn").click(function (event) {
        $(".subscribe p").html("Thanks for your interest!").slideDown({
                        duration: 4000
                    });
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/A2mmP/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `p` element is already displayed when you enter the text and try to slide it down. So no animation is needed.

```
$(function () {
  $("#submitBtn").click(function (event) {
    $(".subscribe p").hide().html("Thanks for your interest!").slideDown(4000);
  });
});
```

Comment: I knew visibility had something to do with it .. Tried other methods to hide it, but didn't work ... Your code works ! Thanks mate ! :D

Comment: You can also hide it on the CSS. Faster that way for the render.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it having the content hidden at first and then just showing it with the `slideDown` function:

HTML

```
<section class="subscribe">
    <button id="submitBtn" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
    <p>Thanks for your interest!</p>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.subscribe p{
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $("#submitBtn").click(function (event) {
        $(".subscribe p").slideDown({duration: 400});
    });
});
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/A2mmP/2/

Answer (score 3):

Your modified code

```
$(function () {
    $("#submitBtn").click(function (event) {
        $(".subscribe p").html("Thanks for your interest!").hide().slideDown('400');
    });
});
```

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/FbELv/)