# jQuery slidedown doesn't work in H1 tag

Tags: jquery, slidedown

So just started learning jQuery. I can't seem to make it work. So I already linked my jQuery to my html document with the script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

I have a `h1` titled `ONE` `TWO` `THREE`. Each word is attributed differently using `<span>` tags. What I want to try out is put a slidedown fucntion on the word `ONE`. So what am I missing here or doing wrong here? Is the fact that my `h1` is `position:fixed` have to do something with this?

html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet'rel="stylesheet" href='style.css'/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
    <h1><span id="ONE">ONE</span><br><span id="TWO">TWO</span><br><span id="THREE">         THREE</span><br></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

css for h1:

```
h1 {position:fixed;
left:14px;
bottom:36px;
margin-bottom:15px;
line-height:40px;
}
```

css code for `ONE`:

```
#ONE {
  font-family:broadway;
  font-size:80px;
  color:#880303;
}
```

jQuery function for `ONE`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ONE').slideDown('slow');    
});
```

Comment: Turn off the Caps Lock please

Comment: Please fix the title of your post

Comment: Can you include your HTML code too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You've given your items fixed position, so they cannot slide.
- And you've not hidden the item you're sliding down, so it cannot be made to appear. (See also [jQuery slideDown() animation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566534/jquery-slidedown-animation-not-working))
- I think a span cannot slide to begin with, I've changed it to div.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="ONEdiv"><h1><span id="ONEspan">ONE</span></h1></div>
    <div id="TWOdiv"><h1>TWO</h1></div>
    <div id="THREEdiv"><h1>THREE</h1></div>
</body>
```

JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ONEdiv').slideDown('slow');
});
```

CSS:

```css
h1 {
line-height:40px;
}

#ONEdiv {
    display:none;
}

#ONEspan {
  font-family:broadway;
  font-size:80px;
  color:#880303;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2uJJ6/3/

Comment: yes I do. I'm building and learning a web page through Codecademy so they have a script.js file

Comment: thank you so much! well being a web design newb, found out that i need a script tag to how my jquery functions. that's what I was missing before.

Comment: last question. so let's say i want them to slide down one by one. In queue. As in, I'd like for ONE to slide down COMPLETELY before TWO slides down

Comment: You can give a third argument to the slideDown function, a callback function that is called when the slidedown has completed. I've used that to trigger the second and third slidedowns. See http://jsfiddle.net/2uJJ6/4/

Comment: great! thanks. I am just testing all these functions. I think i will stick to fade in and add delay to make them appear one by one. many thanks